# WPF: How to make a button background transparent

Tags: wpf, button, wpf-controls, background

I want to know how to set a wpf button background to transparent.

thank you

Answer (score 60):

```
<Button Background="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: Programmatically, its... button.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

Comment: What does this do? Does it make it fully transparent? How to make it semi transparent?

Answer (score 3):

Transparency Declaratively

```
<Button Background="Transparent"/>
```

Transparency programatically

```
this.btnTransparent.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

Semi-transparency declaratively

```
Opacity="0.5"
```

Semi-transparency programmatically

```
this.Opacity = 0.5;
```