# WPF button with transparent background image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to create an image button in WPF. So far I have that solution:

```
<Button Click="btn_Click" Name="btnDelete" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"         Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"     FontWeight="Bold" >
    <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Name="btnDelete_text" Text="Verwijderen" />
         <Image Stretch="Fill" Name="btnDeleteProductImage" Width="90" Height="90" Source="    {StaticResource delete}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

But the problem is that the image I'm using has transparent background, which is shown as white on the button. How I can make it really transparent?

My buttons shows a white background instead of transparent.

[image: Button, which I hv created. White background is shown, instead of transparency./]

Comment: you have to crerate the button image transparent

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Is it the white border around the trashcan image, or the gray background of your button which you want to be transparent? The first one just could be from your image file, which doesn't have a transparent background (you may be using a JPG image instead of PNG).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333540/wpf-how-to-make-a-button-background-transparent

Comment: or maybe you saved a transparent background image/png via an application which doesn't support transparent background like `mspaint`.

Answer (score 1):

The image with transparent background should appear transparent by default (without additional settings). I think the problem is in the image (as it was mentioned in the first comment). It looks like the image was saved with a backgound during some transformation in a editor. Give a try to a different PNG (I assume it is a PNG) with the transparent background and see what it gives.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Image in `PNG` format , i think even if you have a background transparent image format is different.

Comment: It is true by default.